# Наращение или нет наращения?

Tags: числительные, наращение

*Около 500-т, более 700-т, менее 200-т и т. д.*

Примеров можно привести много. А наращение нужно ли и какое?

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно в теме? Как вы сами рашали проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

❶ Если имеются в виду числа **500** (пятьсот), **700** (семьсот) или **200** (двести), то наращение не нужно (это **количественные** числительные):
около 500 тонн, более 700 раз, менее 200 метров.

> Наращение не используется:
> В записи количественных числительных: словарь в 4 томах; работа 2 сотрудников; серия из 12 упражнений.

Из Нацкорпуса:
*На сегодняшний день современной науке известны **около 500** экзопланет...* (Яков Гольштейн. Сёстры Земли);
*Один математик определил число пи с точностью до **более 700** знаков после запятой, а другой нашел ошибки где-то **после 500-го** знака* (Светлана Князева. XX век берет разбег);
*Если учесть ее петляние по тайге, она прошла за это время **не менее 200** километров* (Д. И. Саврасов. Таежные были и небылицы).

❷ Если же имеются в виду сложные прилагательные *пятисотенный, семисотенный, двухсотенный* или *пятисоттонный, семисоттонный, двухсоттонный*, то такие слова можно писать с наращением:
5-сотенный, 7-сотенный, 2-сотенный;
500-тонный, 700-тонный, 200-тонный.

> Если в составе сложных существительных и прилагательных есть числительное, то его можно записать в словесной форме (прописью) или в словесно-цифровой форме (цифрой и присоединяемым дефисом существительным или прилагательным). При использовании словесно-цифровой формы записи буквенные наращения после числительных не пишутся.

Примеры:
*В числе других «жертвой» бедствия стал **200-тонный** Царь-колокол...* (Борис Явелов. Хронограф);
*Краны подняли **500-тонные** затворы водосливов, и через гребенку плотины понеслась многометровая толща воды* (Валерий Ярославцев. Энергетическая звезда Сибири);
*В 1812 году полк имел **5-сотенный** состав* (Казачий словарь).

[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)
[пятисотенный, пятисоттонный](https://www.google.ee/books/edition/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B/CavOAAAAQBAJ?hl=ru&gbpv=1&dq=%225-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&pg=PA370&printsec=frontcover) (Большой универсальный словарь русского языка)

Comment: Спасибо. Факт: известно уже более 6000 экзопланет. :)

Comment: Вполне возможно. Это ведь публикация 2012 года. Да, кстати, я Вам ответила про минус и пробелы (дополнительно).

Comment: Я точно знаю, что открыто 5000—6000 экзопланет. :) А ответ заметил. Это реформы какие-то стали проводиться?